# Don't send mails asp .net application hosted only work in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, localhost, web-hosting

I have a problem when I upload an application to the Web. I want to send a mail to several users but it doesn't work, but when I send in localhost work properly.

Here's my code to send the mail

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage correo = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
correo.To.Add(mail_usuario);
correo.Body = cuerpomensaje;
correo.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
correo.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
correo.IsBodyHtml = true;//false tested too.

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "mail.cscdecision.com";
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("id@domain.com", "IDPass");
//smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sMailEnvioEmpresaServicio , sClaveEmpresaServicio);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

smtp.SendAsync(correo, null);
//smtp.Send(correo);
```

The error is: "Unable to send to all recipients"

Why in the localhost works and in the host No?

```
Error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to all recipients.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: The mailbox is unavailable. 
The server response was: 5.7.1 <csc@cscdecision.com> Access to <ccruz@decision.com.ec> not allowed
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Where is this application deployed?

Comment: the error is "Unable to send the recipents". The host I don't know but an early version of the program work normally.

Comment: When I use smtp.Send(correo) gives me that error but with smtp.SendAsync(Corre) nothing happend

Comment: Error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to all recipients.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: The mailbox is unavailable. 
The server response was: 5.7.1 <csc@cscdecision.com> Access to <ccruz@decision.com.ec> not allowed

Answer (score 0):

have you specified what port the mail server is on?

i.e smtp.port = 25 (or a different port for SSL)

it's possible your host is blocking the port you are using.

Comment: No I don't specified the port.
What I must use??

Comment: Error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to all recipients.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: The mailbox is unavailable. 
The server response was: 5.7.1 <csc@cscdecision.com> Access to <ccruz@decision.com.ec> not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending to same domain name .? If yes so you have to configure that this domain has a remote mail server not localy .

This is common in cpanel hosts .when  the domain has a remote mail server